# Texture spill over android open gl es

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures

I have adapted lesson six of insantydesign's android examples (http://insanitydesign.com/wp/projects/nehe-android-ports/) to work for a 2d square and the texture is displaying fine but I also have other (non textured) shapes drawn on screen and the texture from the square "spills over" to them.

In my on surface created method I have the line
    squaretexture.loadGLTexture(gl, this.context);
which I think may be the problem.

My question is where should I put this line in order to fix my problem?

Comment: Are you disabling texture mapping (`glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)`) before rendering your untextured geometry?

Comment: I just tried that there and am having some weird results. Neither shape gets textured now. Where exactly do I need to put that line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable texturing when you want to draw textures primitives, and disable texturing when you want primitives without a texture. For example:

```
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
drawObjectA();
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
drawObjectB();
```

Object A will be textured, but object B won't.

Comment: Thanks very much.  I had some contradicting code in my ondrawframe method.